# Check if data read from file is equal to INT value given by user

Tags: c, types

I'm learning how to program C and I'm working on a project that requires code to read a value from a file and compare it to a INT value given by the user. To handle this I use this code

```
int id;
static const char filename[] = "ids.txt";
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
int count = 0;
char line[255];
char line2[255];


if ( file != NULL )
{
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) /* read a line */
    {   
        if (id == *line)//PROBLEM IS ON THIS LINE
        {
              //the rest of my code
        }
    }      
}
```

The code runs fine with no errors and when the value of line (the data read) and the value of id (the value given) they are both the same yet the program dose not seem to realize this. The problem occurs with this line of code `if (id == *line)` I'm assuming it has something to do with the data types of the variables but I cant seem to find a fix. Thank you for any help.

Comment: There is no implicit way to do this in C. Please use [`strtol()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtol-wcstol-strtol-l-wcstol-l?view=msvc-170) to extract an integer from the string, or consider using `fscanf()` to read directly from the file (although it depends if there is any other data in each line).

Comment: Aside `id` is uninitialised so it makes no sense comparing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @WeatherVane for an answer to my problem. I use [strtol()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtol-wcstol-strtol-l-wcstol-l?view=msvc-170) to fix my problem the code now looks like this

```
int id;
static const char filename[] = "ids.txt";
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
int count = 0;
char line[255];
char *ptr;
long ret;



if ( file != NULL )
{
    char line[256]; 
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) 
    {
        ret = strtol(line, &ptr, 10);

        if (id == ret)
        {
          //rest of my code
        }
    }
 }
```